# Can the query results be displayed next to the query?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I often have queries that span *lots* of *short* lines.

It's unfortunate that the query results obstruct parts of the query also considering that I have a very wide desktop (3x 1080p monitors next to each other).

You can see the problem on this screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Of course I can use the splitter to make the results tinier, but most part of the whole window is still wasted.

I haven't found any settings that allow a side by side display of query and results or two undock the results.

Is there any setting in SSMS that allows something like this?

Comment: The only thing you can do with SSMS is show the results in a different tab.

Comment: what about rotate the monitor? newer models offer that possibility out of the box and usually windows can recognize the rotation and update the desktop size accordingly without additional software. if you happen to view long listings often may be worth a try.